# Trying to initially hide and then display a results container containing API results when the submit button is clicked, not working

Tags: javascript, hide, display

I'm new to Javascript and am making a basic movie picker. The page starts off with a form to filter a movie pick, which then scrolls down to the results when the submit button is clicked. Whilst I can get the results container to hide and then show, the API results from the movie database are no longer showing. I cannot figure out why.

So, i've been using a couple of simple functions which hide or show an element:

```
 //hide function
    function hideElement(element) {
      element.style.display = 'none'
    }

    //show function
    function showelement(element) {
      element.style.display = 'block';
    }
```

I initially begin with hiding the results container:

```
hideElement(theResultsContainer)
```

Then, when I go to the event listener for the submit button, and to 'else', and then show the container:

```
submitButton.addEventListener("click", () => {

    searchResultsNumber.style.display = 'block';
    hideElement(randomiseAgainButton);
    hideElement(apiResults);
    const selectedGenre = genreDropdown.value;
    const selectedYear = yearDropdown.value;
    const selectedLanguage = languageDropdown.value;

    if (selectedGenre === "" && selectedYear === "" && selectedLanguage === "") {
        unfilledForm.textContent = 'Please make at least one selection.';
        unfilledForm.style.color = 'red';
        searchResults.style.display = 'none';
        hideElement(showMoreButton);
        hideElement(showAllButton);
    } else {
        const selectedOrder = sortDropdown.value;
        showelement(theResultsContainer)
```

So...that works fine. But, the API results are no longer showing. I have a function getMovieInfo, which gathers these results from the movie data base. I'm figuring it has something to do with this function as that's where the info is coming from.

```
function getMovieInfo(movieIdNumber) {
      const tmdbBaseUrl = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/";
      const apiKey = '0db2b210052ac2389b97a0d37eb57c9b';
      const movieId = movieIdNumber;
      async function fetchMovieDetails() {
        const language = 'en-US'; // Change as needed
        const url = `${tmdbBaseUrl}movie/${movieId}?api_key=${apiKey}&language=${language}`;
        try {
          const response = await fetch(url);
          const data = await response.json();
          // Update movie details on the webpage
          const posterPath = data.poster_path ? `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${data.poster_path}` : '';
          const movieTitle = data.title || 'Movie Title';
          const movieOverview = data.overview || 'Movie overview not available.';
          document.getElementById('poster').src = posterPath;
          document.getElementById('movieTitle').textContent = movieTitle;
          document.getElementById('movieOverview').textContent = movieOverview;
          // Show movie details section and center it
          const movieDetailsSection = document.getElementById('movieDetails');
          movieDetailsSection.style.display = 'flex';
          movieDetailsSection.style.alignItems = 'center';
          movieDetailsSection.style.justifyContent = 'center';
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error fetching movie details:', error);
        }
      }
      fetchMovieDetails();
    }
```

The function works fine, as did my webpage before hiding then showing the results container.

Here is the display results function, which lists all relevant movies, and includes a section where you can toggle the API info (which includes movie poster and a synopsis). This is the content no longer showing:

```
function displayResults(results, endIndex) {
  if (results.length === 1) {
    searchResultsNumber.textContent = `Search results ${results.length} film:`;
  } else {
    searchResultsNumber.textContent = `Search results ${results.length} films:`;
  }
  if (results.length >= 1) {
    showelement(showMoreButton);
    showelement(showAllButton);
  } else {
    hideElement(showMoreButton);
  }
  
  resultsText.innerHTML = "";
  
  let activeButton = null;
  let isInfoVisible = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < endIndex && i < results.length; i++) {
    const resultElement = document.createElement("p");
    const movieTitle = results[i].title;
    const director = results[i].director;
    const year = results[i].year;
    resultElement.innerHTML = `<strong>'${movieTitle}'</strong><br>Directed by ${director}, ${year}`;
    resultsText.appendChild(resultElement);
    
    
    const movieInfoButton = document.createElement("div");
    movieInfoButton.classList.add('movie-info-button-container');
    movieInfoButton.innerHTML = '<button class="more-info-button">Want more movie info?</button>';
    
    
    movieInfoButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('Movie info button clicked!');
      console.log('Movie ID:', results[i].movieId); // Access the movieId from the results array
      // Check if there is an active button
      if (activeButton && activeButton !== movieInfoButton) {
        // If there's an active button and it's not the clicked button, revert it back
        activeButton.querySelector('.more-info-button').textContent = 'Want more movie info?';
        hideElement(apiResults); // Hide the API content associated with the previous button
        isInfoVisible = false;
      }
      // Toggle the state and show/hide the API content accordingly
      if (!isInfoVisible) {
        getMovieInfo(results[i].movieId);
        movieInfoButton.querySelector('.more-info-button').textContent = 'Show less';
        isInfoVisible = true;
        activeButton = movieInfoButton; // Update the active button reference
      } else {
        hideElement(apiResults);
        movieInfoButton.querySelector('.more-info-button').textContent = 'Want more movie info?';
        isInfoVisible = false;
        activeButton = null; // Clear the active button reference
      }
    });
    
    
    resultElement.appendChild(movieInfoButton);
  }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be hiding the API results here: `hideElement(apiResults);`, but I see nowhere in your code where you show it again with `showelement(apiResults)`, did you forget to add it?

Comment: The reason it is initially hidden is that I have a toggle button that only shows the API when clicked, which is in another function. That all works fine prior to hiding the results container

Comment: It seems we don't have all the relevant code then, you should include the functions that handle hiding/showing the results container and the API results

Comment: I have updated the above with my display results function, which handles listing the movie search results, and also includes a toggle function to show/reveal the API gathered data. Hope that helps!

Comment: Your code is hard to follow, lots of variables that seem to be global and we don't know where they are coming from, it would help us greatly if you could reduce it to a working minimal example (it could help you too to narrow where your problem comes from). Anyway I still don't see any `showelement(apiResults)` in your code, shouldn't it be for example after the `getMovieInfo(results[i].movieId);` line?